# How to make HTML content inside a web part page searchable?

Tags: html, sharepoint, office365, web-parts, webpartpage

I'm trying to create a page in Office 365 SharePoint where I can add some simple HTML code to a web part section. I have successfully created the pages and made it look the way I want it to. However, I'm having issues getting the content of these pages to show up in the search results of my team site. Is there anyway around it?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use managed metadata properties:

1. From Site Settings --> Search Schema you can search for managed
   properties.

   In this scenario, there's a managed property named ContentSummaryOWSMTXT , and another one named owstaxIdTechnicalSubject . They represent the site columns Content Summary and Technical Subject .
   [image]
2. On a search page, a user enters a query, for example customize search results .

   [image: Query]
3. On a search results page, search results are displayed in a Search Results Web Part. The Web Part uses display templates that specify that the values from the managed properties ContentSummaryOWSMTXT and owstaxIdTechnicalSubject should be displayed in the search results (the display templates also specify many other things, but for now, let's just concentrate on the values of these two managed properties). We can see that the values from the managed properties ContentSummaryOWSMTXT and owstaxIdTechnicalSubject are displayed in the search result.

   [image]

You can also see details such as a small icon next to each search result on the page. These icons represent the site to which the article is published